# Why is Swift failing to decode a simple JSON response?

Tags: ios, json, swift, decode

I am making a POST request, and the API it's calling (hosted on AWS Lambda/Gateway) returns one int. Yet, when Swift tries to handle the API call, its errors out with:

> typeMismatch(Swift.Int, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Int but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Here is the task:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { [weak self] data, _, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(Int.self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.session_id = decoded
                }
            }
            catch {
                print("Error: something went wrong calling api posting session", error)
            }
        }
```

When I make the same call in Postman, the response is just:

```
119
```

I have tried changing the decode line to

```
.decode(String.self, from: data)
```

but then it fails again because of some thread issues.

I have also tried changing the back end to return an actual json object, as well as adding an object to swift, with one property being the desired session_id (with very carefully checked types, tried with Optionals and not), but it returns with error:

> typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))

The weirdest part is that whenever I make a GET request, swift has been decoding everything fine. Where could my issue be?

Comment: Insert the lines `let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!`  and `print(string)` right before the decoding line and see what you get. To avoid *thread issues* use `async/await`

Comment: I suggest you convert your `data` back to a string and check that you are getting what you expect. I just created a `Data` instance from a string containing "119" and decoded it with `Int.self` and it worked correctly.

Comment: As it turns out, the POST request built by Swift was very different than the one that was sent by Postman. Now I gotta figure out why my json body wasn't being properly built